# My raster values are always changed to zero

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, raster, interpolation

I'm uploading a series of XYZ data points onto GIS and the co-ordinates are coming up fine, but some of the Z values are changed to zero - and in some cases, all! I've interpolated the majority of the data, but cannot for those with 0's across the board. Trawled these pages for answers but I just can't get my head around it. Would someone please put me out of my misery?

Answer (score 1):

You do not describe how you are "uploading" your XYZ data. Assuming you are using the ASCII to Raster tool then you need to set your output data type to **FLOAT** if you want the resulting raster to contain numbers with decimal places otherwise it will get truncated to the nearest whole number.